# Drag in View Controller Like Notification Center

Tags: view, controller, notifications, center, drag

I would like to be able to drag in a view controller that contains a webview just like the apple notification center does. If it is possible i would like to be able to drag in 4 view controllers from all four sides of the iPad screen, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) + [Jquery UI Effects](http://jqueryui.com/) + [jquerymobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)